create a file with fallocate, values for it are store in files
I am using a Linux system, and I want to create a file using fallocate. Not a full sized file, I just want to allocate the size I choose on the file system. I have the size value in temp/size and the name value in temp/name, and will store the file in temp/decrypt/.
I tried this:
fallocate -l $(cat temp/size) temp/decrypt/"$(cat temp/name)"

but it fails with:
fallocate failed: Operation not supported

I don't know what is wrong.
$ cat temp/size
1073741824

and
$ cat temp/name
testname123.data

This works, but where is the error?

"Doesn't work" is vague. What does it do? What error messages happen?Did you mean temp/decrypt/$(cat temp/name) ?

See man 1 fallocate, --posix option. Does it help?

What operating system are you using and what filesystem is temp/ on?

I suggest to [edit] the question and simplify the command. Replace the command substitutions with the resulting values as these don't seem to be relevant here. See also https://askubuntu.com/q/563196/1186757 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/31155591/10622916

fallocate --possix -l $(cat temp/size) temp/decrypt/"$(cat temp/name)"
works!
but fallocate writes the complete file with the full size to the disk, thats not what i wanted.
the file should only be created and the storage space should only be allocated but not written.
my most filesystems are etx4/btrfs, they have no problems with creating files by fallocate,
i forgot that temp/decrypt is an udf filesystem, there is it not possible.
